# Why does xsjs not allow table names with lower case?

Tags: javascript, hana

I have the following code.

```
var table "ZNAme";

var connection = $.db.getConnection();
var query;

try{
    query = 'DROP TABLE MYSCHEMA.' + table;
    var drop = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    drop.execute();

   }catch(e){
       $.response.setBody(e.message);
}

The problem is that when I run it it gives me an error saying it can't find the table "ZNAME". For some reason it changes all the chars to upper case. However I'm creating this table also using xsjs and it works fine. I'm able to create the table, add data to it and read the data from it. The only thing I can't do is remove it. It only works if all chars are upper case. Can someone explain to me why this is going on?

var table "ZNAme";

var connection = $.db.getConnection();
var query;

try{
    query = 'DROP TABLE MYSCHEMA.' + table;
    var drop = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    drop.execute();

   }catch(e){
       $.response.setBody(e.message);
}
```

The problem is that when I run it it gives me an error saying it can't find the table "ZNAME". For some reason it changes all the chars to upper case. However I'm creating this table also using xsjs and it works find. I'm able to create the table, add data to it and read the data from it. The only thing I can't do is remove it. Can someone explain to me why this is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use object names with lower case letter by putting them in double-quotation marks (`"<object name here>"`).

So, your code can be changed like this

```
query = 'DROP TABLE MYSCHEMA."' + table + '"';
```

to work.

You'll find this explained in the HANA documentation and in many code examples throughout the developer guides.

Please also make sure that your code is not affected by SQL injection threats. You absolutely need to make sure that your `table` string does only contain a table name and not some other SQL command.
[more on that here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b3d0daf2a98e49ada00bf31b7ca7a42e/2.0.02/en-US/3e9a0491d2af4b908081fbbee12bc8ba.html)